# Can only make 22 pieces of a puzzle visible - mask issue?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am making a jigsaw puzzle in flash. But I have a weird bug. There are 25 pieces, 5x5. I am passing in the background bitmapData to the pieces as they are created.

For each piece I create a single puzzle-shaped mask bitmap.

So each piece contains a bitmap whose bitmapdata is the puzzle texture. And each piece has a mask piece.

When I just show the masks, all 25 pieces are drawn to the stage.

But when I use the piece masks to mask out the texture, I seem to have a hard limit to 22 pieces in which the mask is applied. This happens if I am using 25 peices or even 80 or 100. Each time, only the *last* 22 pieces created will display the texture.

Any ideas?

As Requestsed, showing some code.

```
    public class PuzzlePiece extends Sprite 
    {
        private var maskBitmap:Bitmap;
        private var _texture:BitmapData
        private var bg:Bitmap;
        private static var COUNT:uint
        public function PuzzlePiece() 
        {
            PuzzlePiece.COUNT ++;
            trace("new Piece Made", PuzzlePiece.COUNT);
            filters = [new GlowFilter(0x000000, 1, 16, 16, 1, 3, true), new BevelFilter(4, 45, 0xFFFFFF, 0.75, 0, 0.75, 4, 4, 1, 3, "inner", false)];
            bg = new Bitmap();
            addChild(bg);
            this.mouseChildren = false;
            this.buttonMode = true;
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOver);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onRollOut);
        }

        private function onRollOver(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, { colorTransform: { tint:0xff0000, tintAmount:0.5 }} );
        }

        private function onRollOut(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, { removeTint:true } );
        }

        /**
         * called before set texture
         */     
        public function setmask(b:Bitmap):void {
            addChild(b);
            maskBitmap = b;
            this.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            b.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            this.mask = b;
            trace("piece -> Set Mask", PuzzlePiece.COUNT);                      
        }

        public function get texture():BitmapData 
        {
            return _texture;
        }

        public function set texture(value:BitmapData):void 
        {
            _texture = value;
            bg.bitmapData = _texture;
            trace("piece -> Set Texture", PuzzlePiece.COUNT);

        }
    }

}
```

The parent class creates one of these and passes in a Bitmap to be used as the mask, and sets the bitmapdata to be used as the texture.

Comment: There is a hard [limit](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?16877-Flash-Limits) of 24 blend modes I know of, as well as some size limitation of a masking - but those limits shouldn't apply here. Can you show some code?

Comment: Post some code. There should be no such limit - you are probably doing something weird :)

Comment: Works fine for me. The error could be in the part where you create and add the pieces. You should post that part too.

Comment: @kapep - well I abandoned this approach, due to another "feature" that for some reason when a bitmap masks another bitmap, the hit area includes the transparent areas. So I replaced the bitmap with a vector mask, and both problems are solved: the hit area is correct, and I can have as many pieces as I want. But I am leavint this question open because it remains very mysterious why this would happen. The pieces appear fine unless you use a texture and a mask.

Comment: A long shot...were all the layers locked? Masking will only work if the mask layer and its sublayers are all locked.

Answer (score 0):

The reason when a bitmap masks another bitmap, the hit area includes the transparent areas is a bitmap is a square or rectangle regardless of its contents example: if you have a png file containing a blue circle the  bitmap/png image  is still a square but the outside of the circle is just transparent,but still there making up the size of the bitmap

As i dont have your full code  I presume its the flash deleting some of your images, garbage collection iv had this problem heaps of times with nested Movie clips.

note: you cant have a mask in a mask:

hope this helps

Comment: The problem turned out t be with the filters. Not with transparent pixels, not with nested masks. If i turned off the filters, it works. So the workaround solve was to nest the filter another layer deeper.  But I never found out why the filters were causing the problem at all.